# Why does subprocess.run() return an empty value?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

When i run this:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.run(['/home/nicolas/.local/venvs/docker-compose/bin/python', '-c', "'import sys; print(sys.path[-1])'"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I get an empty `stdout`:

```
CompletedProcess(args=['/home/nicolas/.local/venvs/docker-compose/bin/python', '-c', "'import sys; print(sys.path[-1])'"], returncode=0, stdout=b'')
```

But when i run the command directly in a console i get the result i want:

```
$ /home/nicolas/.local/venvs/docker-compose/bin/python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path[-1])'
/home/nicolas/.local/venvs/docker-compose/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Can someone tell me why ? And/or tell me how can i get the `sys.path` of specific venv?

Comment: Try without the single quotes around `'import sys; print(sys.path[-1])'`. `subprocess` already escapes the arguments for you, so there's no need for those quotes. You're making python evaluate a string literal, so of course there's no output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Aran-Fey said, `subprocess` already escape the arguments. So the double-quotes were not necessary.

This works:

```
>>> subprocess.run(['/home/nicolas/.local/venvs/docker-compose/bin/python', '-c', 'import sys; print(sys.path[-1])'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```